Select multiple sheets then deselect and further select another sheet
I am running a macro across various sheets which looks like
Sub Cost_Reconciliation()
'
' Cost_Reconciliation Macro
' This macro will reconciliate the Premium cost added to cost basis.

     Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", _
        "Sheet3", "Sheet4", "Sheet5", _
        "Sheet6")).Select
    Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
    Range("D69").Copy
    Range("D70").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
        
         Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", _
        "Sheet3", "Sheet4", "Sheet5", _
        "Sheet6")).Select
    Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
    Range("D69").Copy
    Range("D70").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
        
          Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", _
        "Sheet3", "Sheet4", "Sheet5", _
        "Sheet6")).Select
    Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
    Range("D69").Copy
    Range("D70").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
        
          Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", _
        "Sheet3", "Sheet4", "Sheet5", _
        "Sheet6")).Select
    Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
    Range("D69").Copy
    Range("D70").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
        
        Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", _
        "Sheet3", "Sheet4", "Sheet5", _
        "Sheet6")).Select
    Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
    Range("D69").Copy
    Range("D70").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

        Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", _
        "Sheet3", "Sheet4", "Sheet5", _
        "Sheet6")).Select
    Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
    Range("D69").Copy
    Range("D70").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub

I am running the same script multiple times to arrive at no Error Delta referenced in Range("D71") of each sheet. But I am now able successfully write an "Until" script
When I run this code, it completes calculations correctly but keeps all the sheets selected. I would rather like to deselect all of them and select the Input Sheet.
I tried the integrating the following code to the end but it doesn't work.
Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", _
        "Sheet3", "Sheet4", "Sheet5", _
        "Sheet6")).Deselect
    
Sheets("Inputs").Select.Activate
    Range("A1").Select

Can someone help streamline the full script, please!

How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA

Not seeing why you need to activate any of your sheets, considering you're using Sheet1 as your activesheet in each part of your larger macro.  With Sheets(Sheet1) // .Range("D70").Value = .Range("D69").Value // End With seems to be all you're doing

Sheets("Inputs").Select Replace:=True (though True is the default I think) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.select#:~:text=True%20to%20replace%20the%20current%20selection%20with%20the%20specified%20object

Related to selecting the cell at the end of the code: To select a cell you have to make sure its worksheet is active. To activate or select a sheet you have to make sure the workbook is active. You can avoid this by using Application.Goto ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Inputs").Range("A1") if this is still necessary after you have tried Tim Williams' superior code (probalby without the '1 To 6-loop').

Without any selections:
Sub Cost_Reconciliation()
    
    Dim el, wb As Workbook, n As Long, arrSheets
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    arrSheets = Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3", _
                      "Sheet4", "Sheet5", "Sheet6")
    
    For n = 1 To 6 'not clear why this is done 6 times?
        For Each el In arrSheets
            With wb.Worksheets(el)
                .Range("D70").Value = .Range("D69").Value
            End With
        Next el
    Next n
    
    wb.Worksheets("Input").Select
    
End Sub


"multiple times to arrive at no Error Delta referenced in Range("D71")" - perhaps a Do Until Abs(.Range("D71")) < 0.01 : Loop" inside the For each el ..would be more appropriate thanFor n = 1 to 6`.
